# VB.NET - Casting Types

Tags: c#

The following code was taken from the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx

```
int[] values = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
IEnumerator e = ((IEnumerable)values).GetEnumerator(); 
while(e.MoveNext()) 
{ 
Console.Write(e.Current.ToString() + " "); 
}
```

Why is the Array class casted into an IEnumerable?  The Array class implements GetEnumerator as shown on the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

That's not VB, it's C#.

There is no reason to cast the array to `IEnumerable`, it will do exactly the same thing with or without the cast.

Anyhow, using an enumerator to loop through the array is inefficient, as it will box each integer in an object. Using `for` or `foreach` creates code that loops the values without boxing, and without unnecessary range checking:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
  Console.Write(values[i]);
  Console.Write(' ');
}
```

or:

```
foreach (int value in values) {
  Console.Write(value);
  Console.Write(' ');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have retagged the question.  I was asking the question in the context of VB.NET, but I provided a C# example as this is what was on the webpage I was looking at.

Comment: I know what a FOR EACH loop is implemented using an IEnumerator.  How is a FOR loop implemented?

Comment: @w0051977: When you are looping an array, both `for` and `foreach` are implemented with code that is more optimised than just compiling the code as it stands. The `foreach` doesn't use an enumerator to loop an array, the compiler creates code that does the same thing, but without the overhead of the enumerator. When looping through an array, the compiler recognises that the index can never go outside of the array, so accessing `values[i]` is done without the normal range checking of the index.

Comment: What is the point of having an Enumerator if: "The foreach doesn't use an enumerator "

Comment: @w0051977: The `foreach` uses the enumerator for other types, and the array has to have an enumerator for other purposes than using it in `foreach`.